# Difficulty understanding DP states and transitions

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, binary-search

I am tryin to solve a question from JOI Open Contest 2013 titled "watching".http://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/data.cms.ioi-jp.org/open-2013/watching-en.pdf The abridged problem statement is as follows:

**You have p small cameras of length w and q large cameras of width 2w. Given N events spread across a range, find the minimum w such that all events are covered by your cameras.**

Currently, I have understood that I am supposed to binary search against w but I am not sure how to carry out the dp transitions and what the correct states are.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: when *w* is fixed and you cover events from A_0 to A_N sequentially, you can take two decisions at each point:

1. Cover the first yet not covered event *i* with a small camera (this will cover events at all points from A<sub>*i*</sub> to A<sub>*i*</sub> + *w*)
2. Cover the first yet not covered event *i* with a large camera (this will cover events at all points from A<sub>*i*</sub> to A<sub>*i*</sub> + 2 *w*).

This should be enough to derive your states and transitions.

Comment: I would like to ask another question...I feel like after w is fixed, a linear greedy method may work as well (I am not sure), is DP a must?

Comment: @shole no I don't think you can use a greedy method. Suppose w==2 and you have 3 narrow and 2 wide cameras. Your first events are at 1,2,4,5,7,8. You can cover them with either 3 narrow or 2 wide cameras but not narrow+wide. But you can't decide without looking ahead. If there are events at 100, 110, 120 you will need 3 cameras for those. If there are events at 101-108 you will need 2 wide cameras for those. So events at ~100 dictate what decision you can make at ~1.

Comment: thanks...understood now. One more stupid question, is this problem actually bounded knapsack?

Comment: @shole not sure. Probably not. I can't figure out an easy equivalence.